# Questions about LoL Replay and similar software

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

So I stumbled upon a problem with the software LoL-Recorder. While this is a third party software and has actually not too much to do with the actual gameplay of League of Legends I wanted to know whether questions about the software are allowed or not.

The software is basically spectating and recording games for you while you play League and it then saves the file to watch again also in spectator mode (for all you non league players spectator mode is a different mode where you can also watch the camera freely. Basically it's just a replay)

Now this is a Software only for League but I've already seen questions about fraps and similar software. So are questions about problems with this software On or Off topic?

Comment: The short answer is "it's on-topic" - for longer answers, see the ones in the dup.